# Why is JODConverter trowing an UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java.library.path, jodconverter

I have an (Eclipse) Java Project that uses several libraries. Since it wouldnt build anymore and i wanted to get the libraries updated automatically i changed to Maven. Now the Poject builds fine, but JODConverter cannot find a native library anymore:

Exception in thread "jodconverter-offprocmng-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpipe in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2678)

This can be circumvented by specifying the library path like this:

```
-Djava.library.path="/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/"
```

But i wonder: I made a simple test project with JODConverter only and it has the exact same library path (/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib), but has no problem finding the jpipe library on the same system.

What may be the Problem here? / How can i fix this?

Edit: Adding command lines as requested.

Command line of the working test Project:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8
-Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath /home/rydell/eclipse-workspace/JODConverterTests2024/target/classes:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/jodconverter/jodconverter-local/4.4.7/jodconverter-local-4.4.7.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/jodconverter/jodconverter-core/4.4.7/jodconverter-core-4.4.7.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/juh/4.1.2/juh-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/jurt/4.1.2/jurt-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/ridl/4.1.2/ridl-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/unoil/4.1.2/unoil-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.11/slf4j-api-2.0.11.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/2.0.11/slf4j-nop-2.0.11.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/2.11.5/zip4j-2.11.5.jar jodtest.JodTestMain
```

Command line of the "broken" project that needs the java.library.path variable to be set in order to work:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Djava.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8
-Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath /home/rydell/tests/PackingServer_temp/target/classes:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/jodconverter/jodconverter-local/4.4.7/jodconverter-local-4.4.7.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/jodconverter/jodconverter-core/4.4.7/jodconverter-core-4.4.7.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/juh/4.1.2/juh-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/jurt/4.1.2/jurt-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/ridl/4.1.2/ridl-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/openoffice/unoil/4.1.2/unoil-4.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.11/slf4j-api-2.0.11.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.11/slf4j-simple-2.0.11.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/2.11.5/zip4j-2.11.5.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/de/idyl/winzipaes/1.0.1/winzipaes-1.0.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.45/bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/3.0.1/pdfbox-3.0.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-io/3.0.1/pdfbox-io-3.0.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/fontbox/3.0.1/fontbox-3.0.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.10.1/junit-jupiter-5.10.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.10.1/junit-jupiter-api-5.10.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.3.0/opentest4j-1.3.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.10.1/junit-platform-commons-1.10.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.10.1/junit-jupiter-params-5.10.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.10.1/junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.10.1/junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/3.3.2/mariadb-java-client-3.3.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/com/github/waffle/waffle-jna/3.3.0/waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.13.0/jna-5.13.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.13.0/jna-platform-5.13.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/2.0.7/jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.7.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.9.3/caffeine-2.9.3.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.10.0/error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.32.0/checker-qual-3.32.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.6.2/javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.14.0/commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.15.1/commons-io-2.15.1.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.6.0/commons-cli-1.6.0.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.70/bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:/home/rydell/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/barbecue/barbecue/1.5-beta1/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar parser.CODA
--rowDelimiter #
--fieldDelimiter ;
--outputFilenameTemplate ECLIPSE_WORKAROUND_FILENAMETEMPLATE2 /home/rydell/TODO_TODAY_TOMORROW/temp/whatever.odt
```

Comment: How do the command lines of the two differ? In the launch configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) there is a button _Show Command Line_.

Comment: They must. One is a test project that does not need any parameters since it simply coverts a test-odt to pdf - the other one gets the same odt from the command line. 
Buth do not get vm arguments though.

Comment: Please add both command lines to your question: go to _Run > Run Configurations.._ and in the launch configuration hit the _Show Command Line_ button to get the command line.

Comment: Ah - i see. ... i never even recognized that button 

Comment: But i can see nothing suspicious there. Up to now it's "some side effect" supposedly from another library or something like that. But how? Very unsatisfying though ... :-/